# How to refresh datagridview after update in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Here is my code:

```
        Dim sqledit As New SqlCommand
        sqledit = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Branches SET StAddress='" + txtstaddress.Text + "',City='" + txtcity.Text + "',Province='" + txtprovince.Text + "',ContactNo='" + txtcontact.Text + "' WHERE BranchID='" + txtbranchid.Text + "'", con1)
        sqledit.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Branch Information Updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="Edit Branch Information")
        utilities.Refresh()
        Me.Close()
```

I can't get to update it even if I refresh it. Please help!

Comment: Add more details, how do you populate your datagridview?

Comment: Sql Injection alert. Your code is practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Quick example: try putting the text: `';DROP Table Branches;--` in your street address field... or don't if you don't want to restore that table from backup.

Comment: thanks Sir. However, can you help me with the update problem I am encountering?

Comment: You are updating the database directly, you need to reflect the changes in whatever object you have as the datasource of your datagridview, probably by going to the database and getting the information again, once you get the most up to date information from the database the program will reflect the changes in the datagridview.

Answer (score 1):

There is easy way too
you can make a query by your datagridview that call all of your table content
example:

```
SELECT {your table field}
FROM {table name}
```

If you execute this query after changes it will show you the new data on DGV.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is reload the data grid view. Here is the code that explains how to do it

```
Private Sub refreshDatagrid()
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=reerp;User ID=root;Password=root;")
    Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users", con)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim DataAdapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter()
    con.Open()
    DataAdapter1.SelectCommand = sql
    DataAdapter1.Fill(ds, "Users")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "Users"
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

now once you have added data to your grid then just call this method again. here is and example of how you do it

```
   Dim query As String
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("data source=localhost;database=reerp;user id=root;password=root;")

    query = "insert into users (username,password,first_name,last_name,role) values('"
    query = query + tb_username.Text + "','" + tb_password.Text + "','" + tb_firstname.Text + "','" + tb_lastname.Text + "','" + ComboBox_role.Text + "');"
    con.Open()

    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, con)

    Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If (i > 0) Then
        lblMsg.Text = "record is successfully inserted"
        refreshDatagrid()

    Else
        lblMsg.Text = "record is not inserted"
    End If
    con.Close()
```